# Why is Refit with custom handlers converting my GET requests into POST requests? (405 Method Not Allowed)

Tags: c#, http, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient, refit

I have a Xamarin app in which I am using Refit to call my ASP.NET Core Web API backend (.NET 6). On the iOS side of things, I use a custom `System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler` to add the api key and bearer token to the requests. On Android, I do something very similar, but the handler inherits from `Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler`. The code in each file is identical, line for line, except the base classes that each inherits from, which are the standard base handler classes that are typically prescribed for iOS and Android when using Xamarin.

One of the primary `GET` endpoints on my API takes a content body, which contains some potentially large filters. I realize that it's not standard to put a content body in a `GET` request, but I'm doing it because my query filters can be large and complex, and the filters are not suitable for placing in the query string of the request URL.

In the iOS app, these requests work just fine: the requests are issued with the `GET` verb, and the backend processes the request and inspects the body content successfully, and returns a successful `200 OK` response.

On the Android side of things, I'm getting a `405 Method Not Allowed`. The weird thing about this is that the debug output from my handler clearly shows that the request verb is `GET`, but the response from the backend indicates that a `POST` is being sent.

```
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d -   Request]======= Request Begin =======
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d -   Request] GET /api/v1/event/lite?pageIndex=1&pageSize=25 https/2.0
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d -   Request] Host: [omitted]
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d -   Request] apiKey: [omitted]
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d -   Request] Authorization: Bearer
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d -   Request] Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d -   Request] Content:
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d -   Request] {"includeUnpublished":false,"includeOnlyOwnedItems":false,"includeDeleted":false,"startDate":"2022-03-04T00:00:00","duration":"1.00:00:00","isFree":null,"favoriteOption":2,"ageGroupIds":[],"eventIds":[],"venueIds":[],"partyIds":[],"tags":[]}...
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d -   Request] Duration: 00:00:01.1710510
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d -   Request]======= Request End =========

[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response]======= Response Start ======
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] HTTPS/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] api-supported-versions: 1.0
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] Connection: keep-alive
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] Date: Fri, 04 Mar 2022 16:42:42 GMT
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:8968a593-b085-4979-81da-5c5918483840
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] X-Android-Received-Millis: 1646412160790
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 405
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1646412160706
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] Allow: GET, DELETE
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] Content-Length: 225
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] Content:
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] {"error":{"code":"UnsupportedApiVersion","message":"The HTTP resource that matches the request URI '[omitted]' with API version '1' does not support HTTP method 'POST'.","innerError":null}}...
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response] Duration: 00:00:00.0284520
[7de9dcf3-79c2-4b76-a03e-f51af36b1a7d - Response]======= Response End ========
EventApiClient.ReadLite failed: Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed). Retying in 0 ms...
Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).
Error: Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).
```

So, I fired up Charles Proxy and intercepted the request, just to make sure. And sure enough, the outbound request is a `POST`, even though I'm telling Refit to send a `GET`. It's as if Refit is seeing that I've specified body content, and is automatically (and silently) changing the verb of the request from `GET` to `POST`.

I have even manually composed the request in Postman, and I am able to successfully get back data with a `200 OK`, just as I do in my iOS scenario.

Is there something specific to the `AndroidClientHandler` that mangles requests by changing the verb when a content body is present? Or is there something inside of Refit itself that causes this behavior?

UPDATE:
After narrowing it down to being something within `AndroidClientHandler`, I opened an issue Xamarin.Android team here:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6813

UPDATE UPDATE:
Both AndroidClientHandler and NSURLSessionHandler don't like when a body exists in a GET request. So, I simply decided to make my endpoints respond to the POST verb instead of GET. The entire impetus for this is that my query filters can be so large that they're not friendly for putting in a query string, which is typically where filter params go. So, I decided to pass the filters in the request body. That's where problems arose. So, now I'm just using POST for making my queries (because I control both the client and the server), even though that goes against convention. But I don't care...as long as the HTTP calls succeed, I'm not going to be a stickler for HTTP conventions.

Comment: I suspect this is an Android issue.  Have you tried changing the HttpClient in the Android project settings?

Comment: @Jason I don't thinking changing from AndroidClientHandler to the manage handler in the Android project settings will do anything different for me since I'm manually passing my custom AndroidClientHandler implementation to the HttpClient. But I'll try making my Android handler inherit from the default System.Net.Http handler instead. It would be a bummer if that's the solution though, because I want to take advantage of the the more native handler.

Comment: @Jason ok, yep...damn. When I switch my custom handler to inherit from `System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler`, I get back a `200 OK`, as expected. That's really not ideal...for a couple reasons. 1) I want to take advantage of the performance of the more native `AndroidClientHandler`, and 2) now I need to figure out how to load the Charles Proxy root cert into the managed handler (I had it all figured out for the Android handler, so that I could intercept SSL payloads with Charles). Well...I guess I now know where I need to focus my investigation: `AndroidClientHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Scratch all this. It appears that on the iOS side of things, `NSUrlSessionHandler` also does the same thing: it essentially doesn't allow a body in a GET request. I guess perhaps the most straightforward way for me to deal with my issue is to change my GET endpoint to a POST endpoint...even though that feels dirty because it violates the principles of what POST is intended for.

Comment: Bodies in GET requests is not a good idea. Many clients/servers support it, but no guarantees that proxies and caching servers do. It is also specified exactly like this in the HTTP RFC [section 9.3](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3). GET is used to retrieve values and reduce unnecessary network traffic and allowing entities to be cached. Additionally, [section 9.5](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) states POST can be used for: "Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a form, to a data-handling process"

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the purpose of GET and POST a bit.

Comment: Not so much a misunderstanding of GET and POST. Was just trying to coerce things to work in a non-standard way, mainly because my filtering mechanism doesn't play well with being passed in query string params, so I wanted to pass my filter object in the body of the GET. Instead, I'm just querying with a POST instead of a GET, which I don't like. But whatever...it works.